# while loop not working when element is no longer visible - python

Tags: python

Im quite a newbie to this so bear with me.
Im trying to perform a continuous loop of key press and releases on a specific element all the time it is visible. This is what i have:

```
def do something(self):
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable)
  while element.is_displayed():
      ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(element).perform()
      time.sleep(2)
      ActionChains(driver).release(element).perform()
      time.sleep(2)
  driver.quit()
```

the issue is that is seems to still attempt to perform the action even when the element is no longer visible. The element is expected to disappear after a random amount of time, therefore the loop should end but i always get the error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <div id="hearing-test-button" class="btn-mega null"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Comment: Try updating the `element` at the end of the `while` loop: `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable)`...

Comment: tried. same error :(

Comment: Are you sure? Take a look here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3464/element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom-staleelementreferenceexception-when-s/20520#20520 . Also, how many times your while code is executing? 0? 1? More than 1?

Comment: got there eventually. used a try/except in the end

Comment: Did you get it with my suggestion?

Comment: I actually had to go with something wildly different. Im sure it could be made easier but as I say, im a noob so i played around with a try/except and got it working with the below code:

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable)
    while True:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable)
        ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(element).perform()
        time.sleep(quality)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable)
            if True:
                element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(variable)
                ActionChains(driver).release(element).perform()
                time.sleep(quality)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
except NoSuchElementException:
    return False
```